How do I write from a male's POV?
I am a female who is writing from two points of view: one being a female and one being a male. It is also a romance/mystery novel. I noticed when some of my male friends read it they said that some of the phrases were too "girly". I have asked them how and what to change but they only give me vague answers and I was really hoping for a good answer.
Here's some background:

They are both broken teens
The male is the captain of the football team
His parents are divorced but nobody knows
He meets Destiny (the female POV) and slowly falls in love
He ends up helping Destiny find answers to mysteries she's been trying to solve

I hope this helps with the question.

This question – or very similar ones – have been asked before, e.g. https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/4325, https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/17178, https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/53147, https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/27781, https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/39297, https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/61943, or more generally https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/39139. Can you look at the given answers and, if they don't answer your specific problem, how they don't?

Does this answer your question? The opposite sex in first person?

This joke might help to illustrate the (stereotypically) different thought processes of men and women.  (There are many variations; some attribute it to Dave Barry, but I don't know who wrote it.)  Also this similar joke.

I think if the word count of your male protagonists, both thought and spoken, is around 12-15% of the females', you can't do much wrong.

Is it actually important that the internal monologue be realistic to jock male readers? Sometimes a product is more enjoyable if one doesn't look too closely at how it is made.

Men and women experience the world much the same. The differences within one sex are much larger than the average differences between the sexes.
Think of body height: The average height difference between men (178 cm) and women (168 cm) is only ten centimeters, while the difference between the tallest (215) and smallest woman (67 cm) is 148 cm. The same goes for all other human traits.
You can therefore apply most of what you know about women to men as well in your writing, and vice versa. There is even the advice that, to write interesting, non-sterotyped characters, you can try to write them in one gender and then, when you are finished, to change all the pronouns to the opposite gender.
Nevertheless, there are differences between men and women, both biologically and socially, and they result in often strikingly different formative experiences. So if you want to write typical, or even stereotypical, characters, you need to be aware of them.
The most important factor to consider is how the social lives of men and women differ in your culture. Research has shown that boys and girls are often treated differently by their parents and society from a very early age on and how these differences in socialization interact with the biological differences between the sexes. For example, even without parental encouragement, boys seem to prefer technical toys and movement games, while girls more often seek out "social" games (e.g. playing family or household), and these tendencies are further emphasized by the different types of toys and games that are offered to boys versus girls.
Your best approach therefore is to research and remind yourself of in what way and to what extent men and women are the same, and where their experiences often differ. For the latter, it helps to talk to as many men as possible about how they experience being male. You will get the best and most helpful answers if you are open-minded and non-judgmental. Men (like women) will pretty quickly close up if they feel that you feel threatened by their views or scorn them.
That is the background, from which you can then develop an individual character that may be more or less stereotypical.
That is the gist of the answers to the similar questions that I have linked in my comment to your question.

But your question seems to have another aspect as well: your language. Your male readers have criticized some of your phrases as "too girlish".
Many people have the feeling that, for example online, they can tell from the language of a text alone whether a man or a woman has written it. Research supports this hunch. Women, on average, write differently than men. They use different words and different styles, that often are easily recognizable.
Much has to do with the emotional experience of women versus that of men. Male language is often more factual or "sober", while female language is often more emotional. The focus of male narrative is more often on actions and spatial relations, while the focus of female narrative is more often on emotions and social relations. The typical female text, the romantic love story, is full of interiority: All the worries, wishes, feelings etc. that go on in the protagonist's mind. The typical male text, the science fiction action adventure, is full of what the protagonist does and what effects these actions have on the world around him.
So if you want to write from a male versus a female perspective, your narrative must reflect that male experience in its language. You may want to do some research into how male and female language differs.
Another solution would be to choose a third person narrator and narrate all characters from the same narrative perspective. That is, a female narrator can narrate a male character with a female voice and from a female perspective. I find that more interesting than a woman trying to emulate a male voice.
Finally, consider who you are writing for. If your target audience are primarily female, they will not mind a more feminine perspective for the male characters, because they are probably more interested in the emotions and relationships of that character. That is, the text type or genre of your text is more important than the sex or gender of your characters. It is perfectly fine that action heroines read like they were written by men and that the male love interest reads like it was written by a woman. That may be exactly the reason why readers of either gender choose to read that genre.
Which is why you always need to pick beta readers from your target audience.

If we're going for hardcore stereotypes with no nuance, another thing to keep in mind is that men are stereotypically more interested in their partner's physical appearance. This does not need to (read: probably should not) permeate the entire work, but if her appearance is seldom or never mentioned at all, it will come across as odd (for a romance novel, anyway). This doesn't mean he can't have opinions about her personality, but if her personality is the only positive he mentions, some readers might interpret that as a veiled insult.

Years ago I had a similar discussion with a mixed-gender group of writers, and someone said that stuck with me: it's hard for males to explain to female authors how males experience being male, because (at least in many Western societies) we sort of don't actively experience it. For many women, the fact that they're a woman is something they are frequently reminded of; it's often relevant in ways that they need to think about and account for. For many men, they can just go about life and not think about their gender; the male viewpoint is so commonly the default, it just doesn't come up.

@anaximander I think it's more subtle than that though. Men can physically go about life freely and not think about their gender, in a way that women generally can't. However when we get to mental states, women can freely experience, acknowledge and discuss those, whereas every man with mental health issues always has to ask himself "am I even allowed to feel that way?" and then "am I allowed to talk to other people about it?" The same also applies for men's physical health. That's why suicide rates for men are 4x those for women, because men are societally blocked from ever asking for help.

@anaximander ... Most likely the reason the OP's language is seen as "girly" is because men are entirely prohibited from the kinds of conversations that are routine for women. Gay culture is closer to the female experience, but there again we're taking social exclusion/isolation if you behave that way.

I challenge both the central tenet -- "men and women experience the world much the same" -- as well as the rationale ("variation between men and women is much smaller than within each group"). Men often shake their heads about women, and vice versa. And the physiological argument is bogus and proves actually the opposite: Men are much taller, heavier and stronger (both absolute and as muscle/mass). 96% of American women are shorter than the average man. If the psychological makeup is similarly different, it is certainly not "much the same".

I think this is an excellent answer, but I think the words already present such as "often" and "stereotypically" cannot be overemphasized. Men make up roughly half the world's adult population and are enormously diverse with different styles. Not all men fit into stereotypes. Its also noteworthy that in earlier eras it was hardly uncommon for woman to publish under male or gender neutral names and were often not publicly revealed until much, much later...

It sounds like you're hitting an issue that seems to be quite common on Hollywood. Instead of writing strong female leads, they write strong male leads and make them female. This has lead to criticism as they are in no way realistic or positive female role models. There are some great points in this answer but don't forget that stereotypes come about for good reason. Not everyone falls into them but there are many who fit in some way. Utilise that. The male is a football team captain? Use some of the stereotypes from jocks in your school. Being the author, you can pick and choose what you use.

@java-addict301 True. People vary so widely it's hard to draw conclusions about "the male experience" (or any particular gender identity) and as I've only experienced one  myself I can't compare directly. What I took away from it was that for many men the pressures and backlash come about more when they want to depart from the norm, whereas for women it's more about pushing them into certain norms - for men it's about living up to a standard, whereas women are pushed down to fit in. I'm just paraphrasing others though; I'd be interested to hear if any women feel that resonates with them.

Also, @TheBetpet - great response. Gender traits aren't always plot relevant, and people vary so much an individual can be a lot of things regardless. G.R.R. Martin once said "I've always considered women to be people." Opinions on his female characters aside, the principle is spot on. Write a character (who is female), not a female (who is in the story). Decide what traits the plot requires them to have - are they brave, or cruel, or intelligent, or lazy? How do their interactions with the other characters drive the plot? Then write about a character who acts in those ways, and is female.

"Toxic Masculinity"
You state

They are both broken teens
The male is the captain of the football team
His parents are divorced but nobody knows

So you have a teen male from a broken home competing in a highly masculine sport with a bunch of other emotionally crippled testosterone stuffed teen males.
Look at all the traits of toxic masculinity if you want to know how he would behave.

Emotions are something you push deep down and never discuss with anyone for any reason.
Weakness is not acceptable. Weakness is for losers
Being called "gay" is a deadly insult.
Why say a sentence when a word will do. Why say a word if a grunt will suffice.

Basically minimize his talking, avoid talking about feelings as much as possible. He'd be more interested in solving problems than talking about problems. He'd be doing what he can to not be different to his peer group. I'd be expecting him to say stupid things and crude things often, without thinking and then apologize when it doesn't go down well.

I feel that is what one would see from the outside. But how would you narrate a story from that toxic male's point of view? And how does such a toxic character fit a story where he "slowly falls in love" (cited from OP) and helps his love interest "find answers to mysteries she's been trying to solve"? That seems rather untoxic to me.
